# VBA compare cell value to all values of a column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to compare each cell of a column (column1) with all cells in another column (column2), and if the value exists in column2. And if it exists in column1 and the same row in clumn3 states "`TRADABLE`" to highlight it.

With this code it only compares the values to r2 but not to the whole column r and I don't know how to change it

```
Sub mark_cells()


ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Select
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
        If ActiveCell.Value = Range("R2").Value And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "TRADABLE" Then
        ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 46


        End If

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a worksheet match formula.

```
Sub mark_cells()

    dim i as long

    with activesheet

        for i =2 to .cells(.rows.count, "D").end(xlup).row

            if not iserror(application.match(.cells(i, "D").value, .range("R:R"), 0)) and _
               ucase(.cells(i, "B").value2) = "TRADABLE" then

                .cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = 46

            end if
        next i

    end with

end sub
```

A more dynamic method would be a conditional formatting rule.

```
Sub mark_cells()

    With activesheet.range(.cells(2, "D"), .cells(.rows.count, "D").end(xlup))
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=and(C2="TRADABLE", isnumber(match(d2, r:r, 0)))"
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
    End With

end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following formula into `c1`: `=if(countif(a:a;b1) >=1; "Tradable"; "")` and copy paste it to the cells below.